# What would the shape of a singly excited hydrogen atom be?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, hydrogen, orbitals

Suppose a hydrogen atom is excited up to a $\underset{1s}{[\;]} \underset{2s}{[\uparrow]}$ state which takes about 1000 kJ/mol.

Due to electron shielding f orbitals tend to be higher energy than d orbitals which are higher than p orbitals which are higher than s orbitals. But in a hydrogen atom there is only one electron so the 2s and 2p orbitals are equivalent in energy.

So there's no difference in energy with $\underset{1s}{[\;]} \underset{2s}{[\;]} \underset{2p}{[\uparrow \vert \; \vert \;]}$.

Now there are three different symmetrical p orbitals so I guess the end result would still be spherical. But would the radius of the excited hydrogen atom be an overall higher radius then one would typically expect?

I don't know how to square this with [How big is an excited hydrogen atom?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144819/how-big-is-an-excited-hydrogen-atom) which seems to be mostly talking about general approximations for very highly excited states or the fine details of the Schrodinger equation which I don't really understand.

I also don't know if this applies to molecules. Are the 2p orbitals and 2s orbitals equivalent in energy when a hydrogen atom is bounded to another atom? Pi bonds are generally weaker than sigma bonds but I don't know how two equal energy sigma bonds would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a difference in energy between the 2s and 2p levels in hydrogen, which is significant for a wide variety of applications.. The main contribution is called the fine-structure splitting. If you specifically excite to the 2s state you will indeed still be spherically symmetric. The 2P wavefunctions look a bit like dumbbells.