# Has hydrogen ever been used in Quantum Computing?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, hydrogen

What I'm talking about is hydrogen atom *quantum dots*, where a hydrogen atom is embedded in a semiconductor.

The reason for asking is because the Hydrogen atom is a Quantum mechanical system with a countably infinite number of allowed energy states(e.g. the Lyman series and Balmer series).

So can this potentially be used to create an infinite state machine and enable the creation of multi-valued/infinite valued qubits for quantum computing.

Comment: Having a countably infinite number of energy levels is not unique to hydrogen. all atoms have this property. See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144819/how-big-is-an-excited-hydrogen-atom/144826#144826) question for some of the issues with using thi for infinite information storage.

Comment: I don't know about hydrogen atoms specifically, but more generally atomic qubits are definitely a thing, see e.g. http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-4075/49/20/202001. Also, in case you weren't aware, there is also a [dedicated quantumcomputing stackexchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) where you can ask these sorts of questions.

Comment: Note that having an infinite number of possible states is not nearly enough, because you need to also control them coherently in a precise way. As an example, a single photon can also be in an (uncountable) infinity of positions, but that is not enough to build a quantum computer. If you want countably infinite levels, you can also have those with a single photon, via its orbital angular momentum.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert but have read up on QC.  The answer is likely no.  For QC they are using magnetic materials where they can change the spin of the electron(s), this transition is of low energy (easy to use) and also allows entanglement (the magnetic fields (actually EM fields) of one dot affects the magnetic field of the other at high speed close to c.  They don't use 1 atom, they are using a small enough structures that allow close proximity of the dots and their EM fields.  Hydrogen does not make a solid small spot on a semiconductor wafer and I don't think it's magnetic properties are easy to manipulate (if at all), for the visible bands you are taking about the wavelengths are too short for dot to dot communication.